# Angular do not add ng-invalid if we manipulate dom and add required on input element

Tags: angular

I have a layout configuration for my web page. For each control, I have flag-like, read-only, mandatory and hidden.

I have one parent component i.e. `layout.component.ts`, which makes an API call and gets layout configuration information from the Web API.

I have tried to simplify the application and removed API calls. I get the control with the help of Query selector and set `readonly` attribute on the fly but angular do not display ng-invalid class even after applying the `required` attribute on Input Control.

Code:

**layout.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ContentChild, ContentChildren, forwardRef, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent {
  htmlElements: Array<HTMLElement> = new Array<HTMLElement>();
  readonly: boolean = false;

  get layoutContainer(): HTMLElement {
    return this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.layout-conatiner');
  }

  get textControl(): HTMLElement {
    return this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#myText');
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

  }

  setReadonly() {
    this.textControl.setAttribute('required', '');
    this.readonly = true;
  }

  removeReadonly() {
    this.textControl.removeAttribute('required');
    this.readonly = false;
  }
}
```

**layout.component.html**

```html
<p>
  layout works!
</p>

<div *ngIf="!readonly">
  <button (click)="setReadonly()">Make textbox Readonly</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="readonly">
  <button (click)="removeReadonly()">Remove Readonly</button>
</div>


<div class="layout-conatiner">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<app-layout>
  <input type="text" name=" Add_require_on_the_Fly" id="Input-sample" />
</app-layout>
```

**app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Can someone suggest me how can we get the `ng-invalid`/`ng-valid` after applying the `required` attribute on the `input` element on the fly?

Comment: You need to create reactive forms instead. It'll be very easy

Comment: I have already used template driven forms for my application. To change the approach with reactive forms will be quite a lot of work. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the DOM directly in angular, that's one of the biggest mistakes you can make. Any changes you make to the DOM via `querySelector`for instance as you suggested won't have any affect on any angular bindings since angular doesn't know what you're doing.

Instead I would suggest you to add `required` via a `[required]="condition"` attribute, which will allow angular to pick up on any changes made to that attribute.

Also, if you have to do DOM manipulation, you can safely do this via `Renderer` or `Renderer2` (angular 4+). So if the approach above with the `required`binding doesn't work for you. You can add the `required` attribute via the renderer. Check the docs for how it works.

Comment: Yeah, you are right that DOM Manipulation is not good practice but i didn't have any other approach. I have tried with renderer2 but still it do not provide me correct updated ng-invalid css on input control when i add required attribute on it.